# MySQL Configuration Issue - 1 GB Ram - UBuntu

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu

We have 1 GB RAM - 2 Core CPU with Ubuntu
Website is new so very less traffic. But storage is increasing @1% daily which is alarming. Could you please evaluate this SQL Tuner Report and suggest the configuration pls. It's for an e-commerce website.

[https://pastebin.com/tVw80PKu][1]

Comment: 1) This is not a programming question, so you really should ask it on the DBA sister site of SO. 2) Not sure outsourcing DBA activities based on an sql tuner report is a great idea and you may get some pushback on the DBA site as well as your question is not too specific!

Comment: It might be an issue with the specific e-commerce software you are using, not necessarily a MySQL configuration issue. No MySQL configuration file will, by itself, cause the data of your database to grow exponentially. 

If you're seeing an increase in RAM usage, this is normal behavior. It's actually a good idea to try to cache as much of your database in RAM as possible, it's definitely not unheard of for MySQL to be configured to use 1/2 to 2/3 of the entire server's RAM for caching.

Answer (score 0):

1% per day compounded leads to about 40x per year.  You have 23.5MB of data now; that would be about 900MB after a year.  How much disk do you have?  If you have a few GB, what is the problem?

RAM is used as a cache, so you do *not* have to have enough RAM for the entire dataset.  (Performance may suffer.)